# Laravel routes not found, except for the default root route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, homestead

I've installed Laravel with Homestead, and for some reason my routes are not working (404 error), just the default "/" does.

These are other routes I created:

```
Route::get('test', function(){ // it doesn't work like so either: "/test" 
    return "Test";
});

Route::get('user', function(){
    return "User";
});
```

None of them is reached.

If I list all my routes, this is what I get:

```
D:\web\laravel>php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | test     |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | user     |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

Any idea why these are not working? As far as I know, the web server and php in Homestead shouldn't need any additional manual configuration to allow such basic code to work.

EDIT

If I list the routes from within the VM, my routes are not there!:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

This is my shared folder configuration in Homestead.yaml:

```
folders:
    - map: D:/web/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

And the sites set up:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
```

And If I do ***ls*** from /home/vagrant/code:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code$ ls
app      bootstrap      composer.lock  database      phpunit.xml  readme.md  routes      storage  vendor
artisan  composer.json  config         package.json  public       resources  server.php  tests    webpack.mix.js
```

This is the output when I do "vagrant up --provision":

```
PS C:\Homestead> vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    homestead-7: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    homestead-7: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    homestead-7: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    homestead-7: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    homestead-7: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    homestead-7: your host and reload your VM.
    homestead-7:
    homestead-7: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.18_Ubuntu r106667
    homestead-7: VirtualBox Version: 5.2
==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: file...
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
    homestead-7: Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20180424-1628-11jxfyp.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Certificate: homestead.test
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Site: homestead.test
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Cron
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Update Composer
    homestead-7: You are running composer as "root", while "/home/vagrant/.composer" is owned by "vagrant"
    homestead-7: You are already using composer version 1.6.4 (stable channel).
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20180424-1628-1j2nixt.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20180424-1628-ltovu3.sh
```

I've seen this line:

```
homestead-7: Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml
```

It doesn't provide with a detailed information.

Both **D:/web/laravel** and **/home/vagrant/code** have the same content, but I noticed that if I create a random file, call it D:/web/laravel/deleteme.txt, it won't show in /home/vagrant/code even if I reload vagrant.

Comment: Maybe they should be `/test`?

Comment: Nope. I already tried with a slash at the beginning, but didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have your hosts set up properly (is your url something like http://laravel.test)? Also is the 404 you're getting the Laravel error page?

Comment: @devk Yes, laravel.test is placed in the hosts file (otherwise laravel.test wouldn't work and it does). The 404 error page is from Laravel..

Comment: version of laravel?

Comment: Can you do `php artisan route:list` from inside of the VM? Just to check that you have your symlinks set up correctly.

Comment: he already did that, read whole question

Comment: `D:\web\laravel>` doesn't seem like linux path to me.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski Version is 5.6.16

Comment: @devk Ok, you got something! See edited question. The routes are not listed within the VM

Comment: There's your problem. You edited the local version of the project, but it doesn't reflect the one in your VM. Check the [Configuring Shared Folders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#configuring-homestead) part for help with this.

Comment: @devk I've updated the question with the homestead.yaml configuration regarding shared folders.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but it's been a minute since I last used Windows with Homestead and am by no means an expert in this.

Comment: If you run vagrant up --provision (or homestead up --provision) if you have it set up globally, do you see any errors referring to not being able to map folders? You'll have to look through each line to check

Comment: @DJC I've just expanded the question including the results found when running "vagrant up --provision"

Comment: @LuisMartin are you mapping 'sites' in you Homestead.yaml?

Comment: @DJC Yes, I'm doing it. I've also added that info to the question. But I can't see why it would affect. The domain is accessed. It's any route in this domain which is different to root which won't be found.

Comment: Did you try to clear route cache?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you have the mod_rewrite enabled?

Also, check your public directory

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/directory">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this to your config:

from:

```
folders:
- map: D:/web/laravel
  to: /home/vagrant/code
```

to:

```
folders:
- map: D:/web/laravel/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Comment: There's no D:/web/laravel/code directory. My Laravel code sits on the D:/web/laravel directory. Anyway I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Where is your server.php file? Wherever that is, is the directory that needs to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the window, right?

Change

```
folders:
    - map: D:/web/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

to

```
folders:
    - map: D:\web\laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

If you have only one project, run without `--provision` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code
```

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

Or sometime this issue is .htaccess issue try checking **mod_rewrite**

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/directory">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride 'none' /** or something change to all */
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**AllowOverride All**

Hope that gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also check if the .htaccess file is present you can find a default htaccess file for laravel online. If the .htaccess file is present then i'd do a PHP artisan route:clear and PHP artisan config:clear, sometime the configs and routes play up.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```